# app crashes when clicked on the header in onsen ui

Tags: ios, cordova, onsen-ui

We are using onsen ui with cordova to build the mobile application.

we are using the ons list to list the documents and folders as shown in the image, when the list occupies the full screen ie., if there are many items in the list and when we click on top of the back button (ie., on ipad text) then the app crashes.

Any help to solve this issue is highly appreciated.

the platform we are using is ios

[screenshot of the document list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiyvG.png)

Comment: How many items are we talking about? Is it several hundred or even bigger? Also, do you get any errors before it crashes?

Comment: its not about the several hundrends, the list just occupies the full height of the screen. No I didn't get any errors before it crashes

Comment: Can you paste the templates?